# Flutter, Widget next to multiple textlines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I`m trying to make this widget but I have no idea how to make this widget

but "eeeeeeeeee........" starts at 'and' below

I think Flutter is difficult to implement kind of this text things

anyone knows about this issue? thanks

Comment: check `WidgetSpan` official documentation - they say: *"An immutable widget that is embedded inline within text.

The child property is the widget that will be embedded. Children are constrained by the width of the paragraph."*

Comment: @pskink it`s again you ! when I see you in StackOverflow that day is the lucky day thanks

Comment: Can u use Wrap Widget

Comment: @Amit Singh I did use "Wrap" and it didn`t work

Comment: @PaemKacit what the axis u given?

Comment: do not use `Wrap` - what you need is `WidgetSpan` used in `RichText` widget

Comment: @pskink do you know how to set "maxlines" here? when using "Text.rich"

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html - it has `maxLines` property, not `maxlines`

Comment: yah but it seems it doesn`t work..(when it has TextSpan parameter like the example) so I just found the solution.. Instead of Text.rich,   RichText(
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Hello ',
                            style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                            children: <InlineSpan>

Comment: `Text.rich` works just fine: `child: Text.rich(
TextSpan(
children: [
WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.alarm)),
TextSpan(text: 'foo bar ' * 128),
],
),
maxLines: 2,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),`

Comment: @pskink wow when write down "maxLines" in the below side, it works you are right   // Text.rich(maxLines:2, TextSpan(  it does not work